# how to get control id from gridview in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need control id from grid view to use Trigger.

My code is here :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered datatables dataTable" DataKeyNames="folder_path" CellPadding="5" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="attachment_name" HeaderText="Attachment" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" runat="server" OnClick="DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAttach_Id" Value='<%#(Eval("attachment_id").ToString())%>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#2FBDF1" Font-Bold="true" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I need code like...

```
    <Triggers>           
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkDownload" />
    </Triggers>
```

how to get "lnkDownload" id from gridview?

Exception :
[image]

Comment: Where do you want the control to access ? In code behind ?

Comment: I need it in client side..I want to download file.. I use update panel. So it's not working in update panel. For trigger operation, i need particular control from grid view.

Comment: I am getting following error when i use lnkDownload directly."A control with ID 'lnkDownload' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel'."

Comment: Which error you are getting?

Comment: A control with ID 'lnkDownload' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel'.@CoderofCode

Answer (score 1):

You need to register each and every `LinkButton` as an `PostBackTrigger`. After each row is bound in your `GridView`, you'll need to search for the `LinkButton` and register it through code as follows:

```
   protected void gvDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
   {  
       LinkButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("lnkDownload") as LinkButton;  
       ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(lb);  
   }
```

And need to call this on `RowDataBound`event.

You can access the controls from the grid view using the `findcontrol` method

```
  foreach(GridViewRow row in gvDetails.Rows)
  {
     if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
        LinkButton linkButton = (LinkButton )row.FindControl("lnkDownload");
        //Your other code
     }
  }
```

Comment: I got following Exception "Value cannot be null."(ArgumentNullException)

Comment: What code did you tried can you post you r code in question ?

Comment: I used your code in row data bound. Exception occurs when grid is loading

Comment: Can you post the full exception ? Inner exception ?

Comment: Please post the detail exception instead of image. Click on `View Detail ` In exception and then select the details, stacktrace etc. and post it here. From that image it is unable to understand why the exception occurred. It shows message missing parameter `control`. Can you tell on which line the exception occures.

Comment: {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: control"}

Comment: Can you tell on which line the exception occures.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70137/discussion-between-kani-and-coder-of-code).

Answer (score 0):

I've recently encountered this problem as well. 
You can find a control by doing e.row.findcontrol("NameOfControl").

Since I don't fully know what you intend to do, you can retrieve the ClientID by finding the control. Then you can specify the ID of the button by saying Button.ClientID. This will display the ContentHolder1_gridview_0_button_0.

To add attributes, you can do button.Attributes.Add("attribute", "#" + button.ClientID);

The following code is something I've fixed to have the following attribute added to the button. This is so that I can click a button and copy the textbox.
Example:

```
protected void gvListInventoryPassword_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{    
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {         
        HtmlButton buttonPass= (HtmlButton)e.Row.FindControl("buttonPass");
        TextBox txtBox= (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtBox");
        buttonPass.Attributes.Add("data-clipboard-target", "#" + txtBox.ClientID);
    }
}//End of gvListInventoryPassword_RowDataBound function
```